# How to create Particles structure from text in AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, text, particles

I want to take any Text sting  and form from it text formed by particles in actionscript 3 (In flash \ flex) I see I need some lib for this. but all libs Ive seen  do not have such functionalyty by default...

So I want to get something like this

[image]

So Is there any sych lib? or way of doing it with some lib?

It should be Free and Opensource (any license like GPL, LGPL etc will be ok).

Comment: See if [this article](http://www.blogaboutflash.com/2008/08/using-particles-to-fill-dynamic-content.html) helps you.

Answer (score 4):

There's a method for doing this described here:

http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/laboratory/flash/as3-alphabet-particles

There are some other ready-made components here:

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/advanced_text_particles.html

http://www.blogaboutflash.com/2008/08/using-particles-to-fill-dynamic-content.html

... but they might be less useful to you than the first link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Read the question: OP asks for a library. What 'essential part' of a library should I include?